# How to save state of switch button?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, sharedpreferences, android-togglebutton

My application has a Switch. It's used turn on Overlay Service. It works fine, but the problem is in the state of the switch. After I close the app and when I restart the app, its state changed. Always it appears off.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AdView mAdView;
private WindowManager windowManager;
private BillingClient mBillingClient;
Switch aSwitch;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.essential);
    windowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);


    aSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_ph1);

    aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked == true) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext())) {
                        start();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please permit drawing over apps.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        checkDrawOverlayPermission();
                    }
                } else {
                    start();
                }
            } else {
                stop();
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Lookup Sharedpreferences

Comment: Instead of saving the button status, you can check whether your service is running or not and then use that status to check/uncheck your switch button

Answer (score 2):

One brain dead way that occurs to me is to save the state of the button in your shared preferences. This way now in your on create, read the data from shared preferences and use the last stored value as the current state of the switch.

Data stored in shared preference is only deleted if 
1) User uninstall and reinstalls the app
2) User explicitly goes to app settings and clears data

Heres everything you need to know how to use shared preferences: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

If there is any data class available, the state of switch can also be stored at model class level to save the state.
This way it will keep state of switch for each item in listview as well.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Vardaan Sharma mentioned above, there is a way with SharedPreferences, which saves the state persistently. This means that when the app is killed and comes back up, the state can be pulled directly from SharedPreferences.

There is also another way which is not persistent. Using the Bundle supplied by the onCreate method, you could pull the data in onCreate, and then save it to the bundle in the onSaveInstanceState() method. A good example can be found here: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/

Using Google's new ViewModel (supplied in the new Architecture components library that was introduced in Google I/O 2017), you may also save the state and use it. Please see this link for a good example: https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-persistence-onsaveinstancestate-restoring-ui-state-and-loaders-fc7cc4a6c090

Obviously, you could also go with saving the boolean in an SQLite (or some other) database, but I feel like in this situation it's a bit of an overkill.